# Method declaration difference between foo() {}, and foo: function() {}

Tags: javascript

are there any kind of difference between these two types of declarations or is it just a short-hand thing?

```js
const bar = {
  foo: function() { return 0 },
}
```

```js
const bar = {
  foo() { return 0 },
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: Thanks Andy, I have seen this MDN page but I did not see a specific assurance on this.

Comment: You were right, my bad

Comment: Since it says it’s a shorthand then it’s reasonable to expect the two syntaxes are functionally identical.

Comment: Yup, my bad. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An ES5 syntax looks like this:

```
const var = {
  foo: function() { return 0 }
}
```

ECMAScript 2015 allows developer to write a shorter syntax for method definitions on objects.

```
const bar = {
  foo() { return 0 }
}
```

Both are the same and the second syntax is a shorter and modern approach.

Comment: They’re not the same. The method syntax creates a non-constructable function, i.e. `new bar.foo` will fail.